# avoid error message on command crash in ksh

Tags: ksh

I have a program that crashes.  I know it does, it's supposed to in order to test some trap handling.  The crash is expected behavior.

When I run the program from ksh, the shell insists on printing helpful little messages like:

```
./fpe.ksh: line 9: 105778: Floating exception
```

How do I make it stop that?  I want the shell script to ignore the crash and keep going,
without the error message.

Comment: Do you just need to ignore the error messages? `./fpe.ksh 2>/dev/null`

Comment: That discards _all_ error messages.  I just need to ignore this particular type of error, for this one command.

Comment: Can you show what's in line 9?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever program is on line 9:

```
program 2> >(sed '/FLoating exception/d')
```

Comment: I could not get this to work, even a simplified >(cat) swallows all output from `program`

Comment: The error message is not from the program, it's from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Find the command that it's erroring and add 2>&1 to the end e.g:

command > /dev/null 2>&1